# What are the models that needed in the TabCBM

Tags: python, tabular

I am trying to use [TabCBM](https://github.com/mateoespinosa/tabcbm.git) for my own tabular datasets which are provided in CSV file. In the model provided, it required some required models such as:

```
feature_to_concept_model
concept_to_feature_model
```

So, What does these parts means? It is not referred to it in the paper with details. For example, assume that we have tabular data for train with 1000 rows and 7 columns which are features and 1000 elements vector with binary elements. How can we use TabCBM to train a model for test data?

I have tried this code as a simple example based on what is provided out of code and paper explanation:

```
from models.tabcbm import TabCBM
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate random data for X_train and binary labels for y_train
X_train = np.random.randint(7, 100, size=(100, 7))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=100)  # Binary labels
latent_dims = 4  # Number of latent concepts


# Define your feature-to-concepts model
features_to_concepts_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(7,)),  # Input shape should match your data
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dims),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

# Define your concepts-to-labels model
concepts_to_labels_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(latent_dims,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

# Define your features-to-embeddings model with the correct input shape
features_to_embeddings_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(7,)),  # Input shape should match your data
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dims),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])

# TabCBM parameters
tab_cbm_params = dict(
    features_to_concepts_model = features_to_concepts_model,
    features_to_embeddings_model = features_to_embeddings_model,
    concepts_to_labels_model = concepts_to_labels_model,
    mean_inputs=np.mean(X_train, axis=0),
    loss_fn=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),  # Binary classification loss
    latent_dims=latent_dims,
    n_concepts=4,
    n_supervised_concepts=0,
    coherence_reg_weight=0.1,
    diversity_reg_weight=0.1,
    feature_selection_reg_weight=0.1,
    prob_diversity_reg_weight=0.1,
    concept_prediction_weight=0.1,
)

# Create and compile the TabCBM model
ss_tabcbm = TabCBM(
    self_supervised_mode=True,
    **tab_cbm_params,
)

# Compile the model
ss_tabcbm.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Print the model summary
ss_tabcbm.summary()

# Train the model (Ensure X_train and y_train have the correct shapes)
# ss_tabcbm.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_split=0.2, epochs=10, batch_size=256)
```

How ever I get error for this code!